# How to view CFG graphically when debugging LLVM checker with gdb

Tags: c++, clang, llvm

I'm recently learning Clang Static Analyzer and writing my first checker. When I try to debug my checker with GDB, I want to view the CFG generated. I can reach the pointer of the CFG in `AnalysisConsumer::HandleCode()`. According to [LLVM Programmer Manual](http://llvm.org/docs/ProgrammersManual.html#viewing-graphs-while-debugging-code), I should be able to call viewCFG() method of the CFG object. But it requires LangOptions as parameter. Where can I find the LangOptions?

```
void AnalysisConsumer::HandleCode(Decl *D, AnalysisMode Mode,
                                  ExprEngine::InliningModes IMode,
                                  SetOfConstDecls *VisitedCallees) {
  ...
  CFG *DeclCFG = Mgr->getCFG(D);
  if (DeclCFG) {
    unsigned CFGSize = DeclCFG->size();
    MaxCFGSize = MaxCFGSize < CFGSize ? CFGSize : MaxCFGSize;
  }
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found the answer by myself, to view the CFG in this environment just use this:

```
(gdb) call DeclCFG->viewCFG(Mgr->getLangOpts())
```